# C# await async not working

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a button that does the following:

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
doStuff();
}
```

Here is my doStuff function:

```
private async Task doStuff()
{
var nat = new NatDiscoverer();

// we don't want to discover forever, just 5 senconds or less
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(5000);
var device = await nat.DiscoverDeviceAsync(PortMapper.Upnp, cts);            
}
```

Initially I was getting an error but it was because I didn't have the "async Task" in the doStuff() function.

Currently I don't have red lines anymore but I do have the green lines under the button3_Click event for the function doStuff();

It says to consider adding "await" but if I add await in front of doStuff() I get an error.

Am I using this await correctly? How do I get this to work properly?

I'm using the Open.NAT dll just trying to list the open ports.

The warning I'm getting is:
Consider adding the "await" operator to the rest of the call

Thanks,

Comment: `I get an error` <--*what* error?

Comment: `Page.RegisterAsuncTask(doStaff);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make your button click method `async` and `await` your call

```
private async void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     await doStuff();
}
```

Comment: If I do that I still have the green swigglies with the warning:

Consider adding the "await" operator to the rest of the call

Comment: @RobertC `to the rest of the call` <-- what line ru getting that on? does it have await on it?

Comment: I'm getting the warning under the "doStuff()" so it looks like so:

private async void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     await doStuff() <----- this has the swigglies;
}